# ZF2 Doctrine2 App is very slow because of doctrine method calls

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

The request time for the homepage of my app is about 5 seconds although there are only 6 database queries. So I decided to install xdebug with webgrind on my local server to profile my app. There I can see, that I have a huge amount of doctrine method calls, but I don't know really how to interpret this to minify the number of that calls. Maybe someone could give me a hint.

[image: webgrind]

**RestaurantRepository**

```
public function findByCity(City $city) {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('restaurant');
    $queryBuilder->addSelect('cuisines')
        ->addSelect('openingHours')
        ->addSelect('address')
        ->addSelect('zipCode')
        ->addSelect('city')
        ->leftJoin('restaurant.cuisines', 'cuisines')
        ->leftJoin('restaurant.openingHours', 'openingHours')
        ->leftJoin('restaurant.meals', 'meals')
        ->innerJoin('restaurant.address', 'address')
        ->innerJoin('address.zipCode', 'zipCode')
        ->innerJoin('zipCode.city', 'city')
        ->where('zipCode.city = :city')
        ->andWhere('restaurant.state <= :state')
        ->setParameter('city', $city)
        ->setParameter('state', Restaurant::STATE_ENABLED)
        ->orderBy('restaurant.state', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('restaurant.name', 'ASC');

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

[image: Detailed method calls]

Answer (score 0):

You probably load all associations of some of your entities. It is hard to say where the problem is exactly without any more information about your entity definitions and the queries you are executing.

In the doctrine documentation are some suggestions for **[improving performance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/improving-performance.html)** (one of them is about lazy loading associations) that might help you to get on your way.

Comment: I do load a lot of associations (in some cases up to ten) but I have to do this. E. g. in a list of companies I have to load their addresses and some other associations which i have to show in the list. I read that i should use alternative query result formats like array if I just want to show the data. But if I would do that now I would have to refactor all my views, right?

Comment: @DominikBarann What do you mean with *"I read that i should use alternative query result formats like array if I just want to show the data"*? If you need all those associations I would recommend to try to combine combine the queries into one.

Comment: You can use an alternative query result format in your cusomt repositories to return an array instead of an object when the data you fetch is only for display purpose. I think that way you reduce the number of hydrations. But I can't understand how 6 database queries can need 8000 hydration calls...

Answer (score 0):

Install and enable the [ZendDeveloperToolbar module](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools). There you will have a possibility to check how many DB calls you are making with each action.

As you can see on the image, there's a lot of hydration going on under the hood. There's a lot of tutorials on the net how NOT to use Doctrine. I can't tell anything without looking at what you are doing with your entities.

Also make sure you have enabled cache when in production mode so Doctrine don't have to parse mapping information with each request, which is very heavy. You probably are using the Annotation Driver, which is the slowest one.

I can also see you are using the Zend autoloader which is inefficient comparing to Composer. Simply add your modules/src's to the autoload section of composer.json file and let the Composer do the autoloading.

Comment: I already installed ZDT to count my queries. At the homepage which I profiled I only have 6 database queries. So I can't understand where that 8000 calls of the hydratRowData method come from? 

I added one repository method at the thread. So you can see how my repositories look like. Can I do something better there?

I enabled memcache now, but it's not faster anyway. 

Thanks for the hint with the zend autoloader. I added all my modules to composer which is about a half second faster than before!

Comment: I'm using the AnnotationDriver, but I couldn't find an alternative? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Any solutions? I added a more detailed view of the method calls. Maybe you can see something strange there...